# ! Missing \endcsname inserted.<to be read again>\end/ \begin{

Tags: beamer, templates, presentations, frame

I'm trying to create a presentation, but a get this error.
'! Missing \endcsname inserted.'
this is my code:
'''

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Liste}
\begin{itemize}
\item Une liste est une structure de données qui contient une série de valeurs. 
\item Python autorise la construction de liste contenant des valeurs de types différents (par 
exemple entier et chaîne de caractères), ce qui leur confère une grande flexibilité. 
\item Une liste est déclarée par une série de valeurs (n’oubliez pas les guillemets, simples 
 ou  doubles, s’il s’agit de chaînes de caractères) séparées par des virgules, et le tout 
 encadré par des crochets.
 \end{itemize}
\begin{exampleblock}{Exemple}
names=\["Mohamed", "Amine", "Mariem", 1, 2.3 ,True\] \\
print(names)
\end{exampleblock}   
\begin{alertblock}<2->
 \begin{itemize}
 \item Les éléments d'une liste peuvent changer après création\\
 \item List est un type de donnée.
\end{itemize}
 \end{alertblock}
\end{frame}
```

'''

Any help please

Comment: It looks as if your `exampleblock` contains source code. Maybe you get a better output if you place it in some kind of verbatim environment?

Comment: You need a title : `\begin{alertblock}<2->{mon titre}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the mandatory title of the `alertblock`. Even if you don't want a title, you must at least give an empty one like `{}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Liste}
\begin{itemize}
\item Une liste est une structure de données qui contient une série de valeurs. 
\item Python autorise la construction de liste contenant des valeurs de types différents (par 
exemple entier et chaîne de caractères), ce qui leur confère une grande flexibilité. 
\item Une liste est déclarée par une série de valeurs (n’oubliez pas les guillemets, simples 
 ou  doubles, s’il s’agit de chaînes de caractères) séparées par des virgules, et le tout 
 encadré par des crochets.
 \end{itemize}
\begin{exampleblock}{Exemple}
names=\["Mohamed", "Amine", "Mariem", 1, 2.3 ,True\] \\
print(names)
\end{exampleblock}   
\begin{alertblock}<2->{Title}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item Les éléments d'une liste peuvent changer après création\\
 \item List est un type de donnée.
\end{itemize}
 \end{alertblock}
\end{frame}

    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank youu soo much

Comment: @FatmaBelabed You're welcome!